# How do I create two columns for two for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I've been stuck on this for almost 3 hours, I would really appreciate some help.

I basically want the output for the first loop to be on the right and the second one to be on the left.

This is the closest I've gotten to it.

```
PER_CREDIT = 115
INCREMENT = 1.04
YEAR = 2008

for i in range (5):
    PER_CREDIT = PER_CREDIT * INCREMENT
    print ("\t","%.2f" % PER_CREDIT)

for i in range (5):
    YEAR = YEAR + 1
    print(YEAR,"\t")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try combining the two loops, and add a label at the start:

```
PER_CREDIT = 115
INCREMENT = 1.04
YEAR = 2008
print("label1 \t label2")
for i in range (5):
    PER_CREDIT = PER_CREDIT * INCREMENT
    YEAR = YEAR + 1
    print ("%.2f \t" % (PER_CREDIT), YEAR)
```

if you want them to switch places (one on the right and the other on the left) simply use:

```
print (YEAR, "%.2f \t" % (PER_CREDIT))
```

instead of the other print